# Options to serve responsive ads on Google DFP / AdManager iOS

Tags: ios, google-dfp, double-click-advertising, google-ad-manager

Currently I'm trying to setup the Google DFP ads for using a dynamic responsive frame. By this I want to create a banner ad which has a relation to the screen size rather than predefining a size such as 300x250 or 300x240.

The DFPBannerView should be able to take a custom CGRect as argument and the DFP lineitem should take the full size of the CGRect.

I tried this by the following techniques:

- Creating a DFP ad unit with smart banner as primary size. This doesn't work because a lineitem in DFP requires a fixed size. Furthermore, the smart banner seems to be limited to 90 in height.
- Creating a DFP ad unit with the out of page as primary size. I didn't managed to get impressions on this ad unit.

Is there any way Google DFP can be setup for mobile banners to take the full size that is set?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly but I guess you will have to do something like this:
https://www.monetizemore.com/blog/how-to-make-dfp-ad-units-responsive-2/

I used this example to add responsive units to my existing DFP calls.

Note that I don't used this top script of "var useSSL". I used what DFP gives me at unit creation.

I created 2 Ads unit and created 3 sizes that I needeed to each unit (728x90, 468x60 and 320x50). Mine calls for Adsense ads, but sure you can call your line itens.

After all and to be more direct as possible I just added:

```
var mapping = googletag.sizeMapping().

addSize([992, 0], [728, 90]).
addSize([768, 0], [468, 60]).
addSize([320, 0], [320, 50]).build();

var mapping2 = googletag.sizeMapping().

addSize([992, 0], [728, 90]).
addSize([768, 0], [468, 60]).
addSize([320, 0], [320, 50]).build();

googletag.defineSlot('/1071122/Your-ads-div-id1', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-123123123-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping).addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.defineSlot('/1071122/Your-ads-div-id2', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-123123123-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping2).addService(googletag.pubads());
```

While searching for examples to do this I found many tricky methods.
But sincerely don't need nothing of that. I just did it work right now and this thread was one of the "answers" that I found looking for examples. Bookmarked this to help if I was able to do to my site.
If I can, maybe I resume all code to make it work like:

```
<!-- Adsense/DFP default header -->
<script type="text/javascript" async='async' src='https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'></script>
<script>
  var googletag = googletag || {};
  googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
</script>

<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() {

    //here you create a var to map your sizes for this unit - mine is equal in addSizes but you can create how many you need and with different sizes you like. First [992, 0] is for resolution and later [728, 90] is the banner size to this resolution (you can put more than one size for each resolution if you like)
    var mapping = googletag.sizeMapping().

    addSize([992, 0], [728, 90]).
    addSize([768, 0], [468, 60]).
    addSize([320, 0], [320, 50]).build();

    var mapping2 = googletag.sizeMapping().

    addSize([992, 0], [728, 90]).
    addSize([768, 0], [468, 60]).
    addSize([320, 0], [320, 50]).build();

    googletag.defineSlot('/1231231/your-ads-div-id-1', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1231231231231-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping).addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.defineSlot('/1231231/your-ads-div-id-2', [300, 250], 'div-gpt-ad-1231231231231-0').defineSizeMapping(mapping2).addService(googletag.pubads());

    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
    googletag.enableServices();

});
</script>
```

That's it. With this code you have two responsive ad units calling DFP (Ads) Adsense banners with 3 sizes to 3 different resolutions.

And of course, in your HTML you'll have to call these DIVs like:

```
<!-- /1231231/your-ads-div-id-1 -->
<div id="div-gpt-ad-123123123-0">
<script>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-1231231231231-0"); });
</script>
</div>
```